# Are there known mail client applications that built on top of MailKit library?

Tags: mailkit, mimekit

MailKit is a great library but I don't know any mail client that uses it. Is there a list of apps that are built on top of MailKit?

Answer (score 2):

There were 2 mobile phone mail clients written using MailKit that I know of (1 was for Windows Phone and another was for iOS/Android), but the Start-Up's that were making them both went out of business.

There was a web-based mail client that I knew about that could aggregated multiple IMAP accounts for users into a single web UI, but I don't know what happened to that.

Microsoft is using MimeKit and MailKit internally for various products/services but I don't think they've been made public (yet?) and I'm not on any of those teams (I only maintain MimeKit and MailKit in my personal free time and not as part of my job).

The best I can suggest is to do a search on [GitHub](https://github.com) and/or [NuGet.org](https://nuget.org) to see what projects depend on MimeKit/MailKit. I've done that myself a few times, but I haven't found the next [Sparrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparrow_%28email_client%29) yet. I keep hoping I will, though ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yup, there's an actively developed Mail client that uses it. MailKit is the bread and butter of OfficeSuite Mail.